# Check if file has a video stream

Tags: objective-c, video, ffmpeg

I'm on Mac OS X (Objective-C) and I'm looking for a way to determine if a file has a video stream. More specifically, a video stream that can be decoded by FFmpeg. I probably can put something together with Objective-C to see if a file has a QuickTime-compatible video stream but that's not enough. I could try MediaInfo but I don't know which files it can open.. Another option would be running FFmpeg and grep to see if there's a video stream. But this is relatively slow so I looked at FFmpeg's source code to see how they detect it and I couldn't even find out in which file to start.

Comment: did you try ffmpeg -i <filename> ?  That just runs the detection code. Not sure what you were talking about that is slow.

Comment: *relatively slow*. I'm hoping for a faster way.

Comment: Was that answer good enough for you or are you looking for something else?

Comment: You mean about libavformat? Well it's probably the best solution there is but I'm not 100% sure of all the possibilities (including distribution of the code). If no one else replies, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html) on using libavformat and libavcodec (both part of FFMpeg) to get video stream info.